# why does GraphicsEnvironment's getAllFonts() return different fonts than fc-list?

Tags: java, linux, fonts

why does GraphicsEnvironment's getAllFonts() method return different fonts 
than fc-list (on linux?)

fc-list returns:

```
Abyssinica SIL:style=Regular
Cantarell:style=Bold
Cantarell:style=Regular
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold Italic
Century Schoolbook L:style=Italic
Century Schoolbook L:style=Roman
Courier:style=Regular
DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed:style=Condensed Bold,Bold
DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed:style=Condensed Bold Oblique,Bold Oblique
DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed:style=Condensed,Book
DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed:style=Condensed Oblique,Oblique
DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Light:style=ExtraLight
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Oblique
DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
DejaVu Sans:style=Bold Oblique
DejaVu Sans:style=Book
DejaVu Sans:style=Oblique
DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed:style=Condensed Bold,Bold
DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed:style=Condensed Bold Italic,Bold Italic
DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed:style=Condensed,Book
DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed:style=Condensed Italic,Italic
DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
DejaVu Serif:style=Bold Italic
DejaVu Serif:style=Book
DejaVu Serif:style=Italic
Dingbats:style=Regular
...
```

Whereas

getAllFonts in GraphicsEnvironment returns:

```
AbyssinicaSIL
CenturySchL-Bold
CenturySchL-BoldItal
CenturySchL-Ital
CenturySchL-Roma
DejaVuSans
DejaVuSans-Bold
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique
DejaVuSansCondensed
DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold
DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique
DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique
DejaVuSans-ExtraLight
DejaVuSansMono
DejaVuSansMono-Bold
DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique
DejaVuSansMono-Oblique
DejaVuSans-Oblique
DejaVuSerif
DejaVuSerif-Bold
DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic
DejaVuSerifCondensed
DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold
DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic
DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic
DejaVuSerif-Italic
Dialog.bold
Dialog.bolditalic
Dialog.italic
Dialog.plain
DialogInput.bold
DialogInput.bolditalic
DialogInput.italic
DialogInput.plain
Dingbats
...
```

Comparing those two different lists, teach list has fonts not available to the other.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

---

Further note:

The reason I asked this in the first place, is that I am trying to track down some UI issues where a font defined on one OS (e.g. Solaris) is different than on another (e.g Linux).

I think the problem is that while both OSes have the same logical font (Dialog), 
they do not necessarily have the same physical fonts.

But if you make a font like:

```
Font STANDARD_FONT = new Font("Dialog", 0, 12);
```

it is not guaranteed to be the same everywhere.

I was hoping that I could look at the fonts available on the two systems and see which were available via fc-list, but the font reported by java (Dialog.plain) is not a listed font according to fc-list.

So, if I define a logical font via new Font("Dialog", 0, 12), 
the APIs available via java (e.g. font.getName() etc) show:

postscript - Dialog.plain
family - Dialog
name - Dialog
fontName - Dialog.plain
size - 12

how can I tell exactly what physical font java has chosen to use for the Dialog Family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font families present exclusively in `getAllFonts()` are not physical fonts, meaning they aren't font files on your computer, so `fc-list` doesn't locate them. They are font families common in every Java implementation, and are mapped to physical fonts.

> Logical fonts are the five font families defined by the Java platform which must be supported by any Java runtime environment: Serif, SansSerif, Monospaced, Dialog, and DialogInput. These logical fonts are not actual font libraries. Instead, the logical font names are mapped to physical fonts by the Java runtime environment.

As for the font families exclusive to `fc-list`, they are most likely the physical fonts on your system that aren't supported by the Java implementation you are running.  The only font type that a Java implementation is required to support is TrueType; the fonts exclusive to `fc-list` might not be TrueType.

> All implementations of the Java Platform must support TrueType fonts; support for other font technologies is implementation dependent.

Source: [Java's `Font` API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

Comment: thanks for the clarification Vulcan.   I have added some notes above for what I am seeing vs what I cannot see,

Comment: To discover what each logical font maps to, you will need to read [Java's font configuration files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html).

Comment: Seems a bit of an ugly solution, as there is not way to definitely know which properties file it is picking. I am making a good guess based on the java api guide, but it would be nicer if there was an API that would print the name of the physical font it selected.  Thanks for the great info Vulcan, very clear advice.